# Unfortunately "Project_Name" has been Stopeed Error in Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I am a newbie in android developement. I am just making a simple project to save the font size of the text entered everytime seekbar moves.

I completed the project with no errors but when I run the application it shows error message in Emulator says "Unfortunately SharedPreferences has been Stopped".

I have searched in below links as well for this and applied all but there was no such error in my case:

1. [Unfortunately app has stopped in Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300947/unfortunately-app-has-stopped-in-android-emulator)
2. [Unfortunately HelloListView has stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009030/unfortunately-hellolistview-has-stopped/)
3. [Unfortunately, *name of app* has stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664562/unfortunately-name-of-app-has-stopped)
4. [Unfortunately, MyApp has Stopped In Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133775/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-in-emulator)
5. [unfortunately app has stopped in emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663515/unfortunately-app-has-stopped-in-emulator)
6. [unfortunately the application has stoped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196632/unfortunately-the-application-has-stoped)
7. [Unfortunately Project_Name Has Stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441120/unfortunately-project-name-has-stopped)
8. ["Unfortunately, app name has stopped." android device or emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436909/unfortunately-app-name-has-stopped-android-device-or-emulator)

and few more.

Here's project's LAYOUT file is (sharedprefer.xml):

```
<Seekbar android:id="@+id/sb"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<EditText android:id="@+id/et"
    android:hint="@string/txt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/s" />
```

.Java file is (Main.java) :

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity {

```
private SharedPreferences pref;
private String pName = "MyPref";
private EditText et;
private SeekBar sb;
private Button b;

private static final String FONT_SIZE_KEY = "fontsize";
private final static String TEXT_VALUE_KEY = "textvalue";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sharedprefer);

    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
    sb = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sb);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            pref = getSharedPreferences(pName, MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putFloat(FONT_SIZE_KEY, et.getTextSize());
            editor.putString(TEXT_VALUE_KEY, et.getText().toString());

            editor.commit();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Saved" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    pref = getSharedPreferences(pName, MODE_PRIVATE);
    float fontsize = pref.getFloat(FONT_SIZE_KEY, 14);

    sb.setProgress((int)fontsize);
    et.setText(pref.getString(TEXT_VALUE_KEY, ""));
    et.setTextSize(sb.getProgress());

    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar sbar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            et.setTextSize(progress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

and I found errors in LOGCAT are :

```
07-17 13:12:18.369: I/Process(576): Sending signal. PID: 576 SIG: 9
07-17 13:12:30.760: D/AndroidRuntime(622): Shutting down VM
07-17 13:12:30.760: W/dalvikvm(622): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nsa.sharedpreferences/com.nsa.sharedpreferences.Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class Seekbar
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class Seekbar
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at com.nsa.sharedpreferences.Main.onCreate(Main.java:29)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  ... 11 more
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.Seekbar
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:636)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
07-17 13:12:30.810: E/AndroidRuntime(622):  ... 21 more
```

Please tell me what can be its solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
<Seekbar android:id="@+id/sb"
```

with

```
<SeekBar android:id="@+id/sb"
```

the `b` has to be a capital `B`

Comment: Thanks pal ! it worked. It was just skipped from my vision. Anyway thanks. Also, wanted to know that such kind of error comes only due to error in our layout or someother reason is also there as I am facing same problem with my other application which is very huge so, checking each layout will be difficult

Comment: if you get an InflateException tipically is due of errors inside the layout (typo for instance)